# How to square the left and right sides of an equation at the same time？

Tags: equation-solving

There is an equation :

```
-2 == Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 - y)^2] - Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2]
```

There are two radicals on the right side of equal to coincidence，The following are about six steps of our manual calculation:

1. to operate so that the left and right sides of the equation 
   contain a radical after the item is shifted，the result is :

```
Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2] - 2 == Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 - y)^2]
```

2. square the left and right sides of the door - to -
   door formula at the same time, and the result is :

```
4 + x^2 + (2 - y)^2 - 4 Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2] == x^2 + (y + 2)^2
```

3. After sorting, we can get :

```
4 - 4 Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2] - 8 y == 0
```

4. Then move the radical to the other side of the equal sign :

```
4 - 8 y == 4 Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2]
```

5. Divide the left and right sides by the common factor to get :

```
1 - 2 y == Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2]
```

6. Then square the left and right sides again to get :

```
3 + x^2 == 3 y^2
```

**To sum up :
For an equation with two roots, the equation without roots can be obtained by simplifying the equation in this way. How can we use simultaneous square operation on both sides of the equation?
the equation is**

```
Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2] == 2 + Sqrt[x^2 + (2 + y)^2]
```

**How to square the left and right sides of this formula at the same time to get this result:**

```
3 + x^2 == 3 y^2
```

Comment: You can use `ApplySides` to apply a function to both sides of an equation, e.g `ApplySides[#^2 &, eqn]` . However, this doesn't get the form you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first steps may be as follows.

```
Map[#^2 &, Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 + y)^2] == 2 + Sqrt[x^2 + (2 + y)^2]]
```

> `x^2 + (-2 + y)^2 == (2 + Sqrt[x^2 + (2 + y)^2])^2`

```
Expand[%]
```

> `4 + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 == 8 + x^2 + 4 y + y^2 + 4 Sqrt[x^2 + (2 + y)^2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can let Mathematica do the work for you if you encode it as polynomials. For example, consider instead the three equivalent polynomials equations

```
eqs = {-2 == z1 - z2, z1^2 == x^2 + (-2 - y)^2, z2^2 == x^2 + (2 - y)^2}
```

from which you can ask if it is possible to *eliminate* the auxiliary variables `z1` and `z2`

```
Eliminate[rels, {z1, z2}]
```

to obtain

> -3 + 3 y^2 == x^2

in one step.

Comment: Tke a look at the result of `Reduce[-2 == Sqrt[x^2 + (-2 - y)^2] - Sqrt[x^2 + (2 - y)^2], {x, 
  y}, Reals]`.